# MySQL: Connecting as root in workbench does not work

Tags: mysql

I have intsalled mysql on my Mac, confirmed its working and can view all the tables in the terminal:

> mysql -u root -p

Entered password xxxx

However, I next tried to use MySQL workbench setting up a local connection using these settings...

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3306
Username: root
```

My problem is that this will not connect unless I use the username `root@localhost`, however I don't know what root@localhost is and it does not have any permissions to create tables nor can I see my tables created as root.

Why in workbench can I not connect as the root user?

Thanks

Comment: is this a fresh install ?

Comment: try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` as host.

Comment: @Up_One no I think I had a version install sometime ago but removed it.

Comment: @Christian Mark localhost gives the same

Comment: have you set a password for the root user yet ?

Comment: In my user table using terminal I can see a user call 127.0.0.1|root and localhost|root but only localhost|root seems to have a hashed password

Comment: yes I set a password during the install and its the one I use to connect in the terminal which works, but same password in workben does not work with root only root@localhost

Comment: try altering the password and "flush privileges;" next try again to connect !

Comment: UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;

Comment: @Up_One that worked! thanks. flush privileges worked for me. although I still think i should see the mysql table as root user i don't but root now works!

Comment: @Up_One do you want to add an answer for me to accept? Thanks

Comment: @Spike ! that was a first ! kkkk Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , try to do this :

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
exit;
```

Thx !